# Replicating multiple models at once

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2.

If I want to duplicate a model I can use the following:

```
$newModel = $currentModel->replicate();
$newModel->save();
```

However I have this inside a loop, like so:

```
foreach ($this->models as $currentModel) {
    $newModel = $currentModel->replicate();
    $newModel->save();
}
```

Which obviously causes a several DB calls.  I want something more efficient, so I can loop through my models and then outside of the loop use one DB call to write them all in one go.

In Laravel is there a way to replicate multiple models in one go?

Comment: I think you can do it like this `DB::table('table_name')->insert(array_map(function ($model) {
            return $model->getAttributes();
        }, $newModels))` after collecting the new models in replicationg loop !!

Comment: Hi @Maraboc I think your approach has merit, I will try this myself

Comment: Is it working for you ??

Comment: @Maraboc I used something similar - I used the loop to create an array and then wrote the entire array in one go using `DB::table()->insert()` - suggest this as an answer and I will mark you as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `insert` statment of DB query builder like this :

```
foreach ($this->models as $currentModel) {
    $newModel = $currentModel->replicate()
    $newModels[] = $newModel->toArray();
}
DB::table('table_name')->insert($newModels);
```

Answer (score 0):

No it not possible duplicate more than one model, you can see in the api documentation:
https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_replicate

So if you would duplicate X models you need loop them and you can speific (with array parameter) wich columns you would like to not copy